# Spock spy - spy class that used in function (Java)

Tags: java, groovy, spock, spy

How can I spy for the Class File in anthoer function in class?
Works for the test when I use new File in the test but not in my class.

```
public class Clazz {
    public void fun(String path) {
        File file = new File(path);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }
    }
}


//Spock-test
class test extends Specification {
    given:
    GroovySpy(File, global: true, useObjenesis: true)
    def mockFile = Mock(File) {
      exists() >> true
    }
    new File(path) >> {mockFile}

    when:
    Clazz.fun("test.file")

    then:
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't be easier if you pass `File file` instead of `String path`? If you use `File` to get content of some file you could even generalize to `InputStream` so you can use `FileInputStream` as well as other input stream types.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already thought about that, but it's makes me another problem with something else.
Is it even possible to do what I want?

Comment: I use spock for years and I have never mock global class, because it smells with bad design decisions. I would strongly suggest rethinking your class design and simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

From official spock docs about **Spy**:

> Think twice before using this feature. It might be better to change
>   the design of the code under specification.

http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html

And there are no reason to use spy object in test like that. If you don't like to redesign code, you can always use groovy metaprogramming:

```
File.metaClass.exists = {true}
```

Comment: Thanks.
The problem is that overwrite the method only in spock-test and not in the Java class

Comment: yeah. It works in groovy code. But why do you need to use it in your classes?

Comment: When I write unit test, there is no right path and then I get throw because the file not exists. The rest of the method not continue.